# mp3 file corrupted after downloading it from libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl, ibm-watson

I'm using libcurl to access the IBM Watson API, and I'm downloading an mp3 file, but the downloaded file is corrupted. I was expecting a "hello world" message, but instead, I get either a corrupted mp3 file or the sounds of hell. I guess that the error is coming from when I convert the response to a `const char *` and it lost data because I'm writing binary data and C++ thinks that the `null` keywords are string enders. It outputs two different strings. Is there any fix for this?

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
size_t CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_StdString(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string *s)
{
    size_t newLength = size * nmemb;
    try
    {
        s->append((char*)contents, newLength);
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc &e)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return newLength;
}
std::string CurlGetResponse(std::string url) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    std::string response;

    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "apikey");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "API Key");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L); //only for https
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L); //only for https
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CurlWrite_CallbackFunc_StdString);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return response;
}
int main()
{
    std::string response = CurlGetResponse("url");
    std::cout << response.data();
    std::cout << response;
    std::fstream file;
    file.open("C:\\Users\\maste\\HelloWorld_1.mp3", std::ios::binary);
    file.write(response, sizeof(response));
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't show us a [mcve]. In the `main` function what is `response`? If it's a `std::string` object then the problem is `sizeof(response)` which is the size of the `std::string` object, not the length of the string it contains. If `response` is a pointer then `sizeof(response)` is the size of the pointer, not what it might point to.

Comment: `response` is the binary data of the mp3 (from IBM Watson) and `response` is returned as a string

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mcve]. Where in `main` is `response` defined? What is its actual type? And please consider what I said about `sizeof(response)`. Unless `response` is an actual compile-time C-style array then `sizeof` will not work as you seem to expect.

Comment: oh I see what you mean, I forgot to add a line of code that is critical, how silly of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
file.write(response, sizeof(response));
```

contains two errors:

1. First of all it passes the `std::string` object as an argument, but `write` expects a pointer to the bytes to write. You need to pass e.g. `response.data()`.
2. The second problem (which I also mentioned in the comments) is that `sizeof(response)` is the size of the `std::string` object itself, not the string it contains. You need to use `response.size()` to get the size of the actual string.

All in all the statement should look like:

```
file.write(response.data(), response.size());
```